# firebase remove function name from url

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, routes, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple express app like this.

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    ...handle request...
});

...

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I am deploying on firebase. and when I deploy it it creates a new route by the name of the function like this: `https://us-central1-[projectname].cloudfunctions.net/app`

this is because I put `exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);`
so how can I deploy and make it work without the `/app` at the end?
 I need this because I am having issue with the references on my front end which use routes like `"/login"`, which in this case won't work since it had added `app` requiring all routes to be like  `"/app/login"`

I even tried `export default app` but no luck.

how can I deploy with out the function name as a route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `/[exportname]` from the first part of a URL hosted on `cloudfunctions.net` is not possible as this is how the functions are triggered.

Ideally rather than serve resources from the `cloudfunctions.net` domain, you place your [functions behind Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) where you can instead use a URL like `https://yourapp.example.com/login` which will play nicely with Express.

However, if you wish to call `https://us-central1-[projectname].cloudfunctions.net/app/login` and have it behave as if it was called from `https://us-central1-[projectname].cloudfunctions.net/login`, you can make use of a conditional URL rewrite. The example below will strip `/app` from the URL if-and-only-if the hostname ends in `cloudfunctions.net` and the URL also starts with `"/app"`, then handing over to the other routes.

```js
import express from "express";

function removePathForCloudFunctionsDomain(path) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    const rawUrl = req.url; // stash original URL

    // do nothing if not on cloudfunctions.net or path doesn't match
    if (!req.hostname.endsWith("cloudfunctions.net") || !rawUrl.startsWith(path)) {
      return next();
    }
    
    // if here, trim path off of the request's URL
    req.url = req.originalUrl = rawUrl.slice(path.length);
    
    // hand over to other app.get(), app.use(), etc.
    next('route');
  }
}

const app = express();

app.use(removePathForCloudFunctionsDomain("/app"));

/* other routes */

export app;
```